# In Microsoft Project why is my actual duration calculating to 0 days?

Tags: ms-project, planning, scheduling, tracking

I had set a baseline previously and I am now updating to show what has actually happened.  I went into the task information and changed the "start" and "finish" dates to what actually happened.  When I hit ok MS Project then changes the "actual duration" to 0 days... even though it should be 7 days.  Any ideas why this happens?

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behaviour in MS-Project 2013. Can you provide exact repeatable steps and also specify the MS-Project version you are using (in a tag)?

Comment: I'm using MS Project 2010.  The steps in the original question are as exact and repeatable as I can think of.

Comment: I think it had something to do with trying to set an actual finish date that is earlier than a predecessor's scheduled finish date.  I removed the predecessor and then the problem stopped.  Slightly frustrating because I then loose traceability to the baseline dependency relationships.  Thank you for trying to look in to this Marv Mills

Answer (score 1):

Display the remaining duration field.
Open Task Information, go to the advanced tab. Uncheck the box for "mark as milestone".